# HTML5 canvas performance on small vs. large files

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, html5-canvas

I seem to be experiencing varying performance using an HTML5 canvas based on the memory size of the page... perhaps the number of images (off-screen canvases) that are loaded. How to I best locate the source of the performance problem? Or does anyone know if in fact there is a performance issue when there's a lot of data loaded, even if it isn't all being used at once?

[Here's an example of good performance.](http://sgdk2.enigmadream.com/ben/CleanGame.html) I have a relatively simple map. It's between 700 and 800 KB. You can drag to scroll around this map relatively smoothly.

[There's another file](http://sgdk2.enigmadream.com/ben/LokRevivalHtml5.7z) (which you may not want to look at due to its large size).

It's about 16 MB and contains dozens, maybe on the order of a hundred images/canvases.  It draws a smaller view so it should go faster. But it doesn't. Many of the maps lag quite severely compared to the simpler demo.

I could try to instrument the code to start timing things, but I have not done this in JavaScript before, and could use some help. If there are easier ways to locate the source of performance problems, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Chrome and Chromium, you can open the developer tools (tools->developer tools) and then click on "Profiles". Press the circle at the bottom, let the canvas redraw and then click on the circle again. This gives you a profile that shows how much time was spent where.

Comment: Thanks!  That's quite helpful.  Indeed the function where most of the time was spent is in the function that draws on the canvas.  I need to investigate it a bit more and might have a follow up question.  I will compare the number of times that function is called with the number of times the simple example calls it.  If it is less (as expected) I may have follow up questions.

Comment: I decided to post my current follow-up question as a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965592/html5-canvas-slow-on-chrome-but-fast-on-firefox so I'll accept this answer for this question.

Comment: I also found chrome://tracing to be somewhat informative, but not quite useful with my level of experience.  I posted some results in my follow up question, but I don't know what to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on some complex canvas stuff where rendering performance mattered to me.

I wrote some test cases in jsperf and came to the conclusion that a rule of thumb is that a source offscreen canvas should never be more than 65536 pixels.

I haven't yet come to a conclusion about why this is, but likely a data structure or data type has to be changed when dealing with large *source* canvases.

putImageData showed similar results.
destination canvas size didn't seem to matter.

Here are some tests I wrote that explore this performance limitation:
http://jsperf.com/magic-canvas/2
http://jsperf.com/pixel-count-matters/2